# How to resolve : An attribute argument must be a constant expression error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I am trying to perform basic compare validation for two fields - password and confirmpassword.

For the error message, I am calling reference to fetch value for errormsg.
If I use, I get the following error

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

```
[Compare(Constants.NewPassword, ErrorMessage = businessprovider.GetValueByKey(Constants.ErrorMsg))]
```

Comment: Attributes are metadata and must be known at compile time and therefore must be constants. You cannot use a method in an attribute

Comment: thanks for the response. can you provide a answer of how it can be done?

Comment: How what can be done? You cannot use a method to get the error message. You need to provide a constant.